# Evaluate EL in the bean validation message before it is rendered

Tags: jsf-2, el, bean-validation, phaselistener

I am trying to evaluate validation messages before rendered to UI. The reason for all this I am trying to do is, if i use

```
@NotEmpty(message="{person.lastName.notNull}")
private String lastName;
```

In my resource bundle the value for the key is as follows:

> Please enter lastname #{account.profile.name.something}

When the input field is validated message displayed as is, i.e. the runtime expression value is not being resolved. I am trying to fill up the commented code in the `if` loop of the following phase listener.

```
public Class EvaluateMessageListener implements PhaseListener {

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {  
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;  
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {   
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        List<FacesMessage> messageList = facesContext.getMessageList();  
        if (messageList != null) {  
            //loop through the messagelist,evaluate message and add message to FacesContext
        }  
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    } 

}
```

How can I achieve this?